# What is the difference between Component.providers and Component.viewProviders?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to share a service between a parent component and it's child, and I was wondering what is the functionality of viewProviders. What is it's difference with providers ?

Answer (score 1):

Lets take this example

```
class Greeter {
   greet(name:string) {
     return 'Hello ' + name + '!';
   }
}    
@Component({
  selector: 'greet',
  viewProviders: [
    Greeter
  ],
  template: `<needs-greeter></needs-greeter>`    
})
class HelloWorld {
}
```

In the example, there is no difference between providers and viewProviders because HelloWorld's template doesn't use `<ng-content>`. If you were projecting content within `<ng-content>...</ng-content>`, then Greeter couldn't be injected in the projected content because you're using

```
viewProviders: [Greeter]
```

If you wanted Greeter to potentially be injected into the projected content, you'd use

```
providers: [Greeter]
```

So `viewProviders` limits the provider to children other than projected content, while `providers` allows all children to use the provider. The value is that `viewProviders` allows you to prevent projected content from messing with your services, which could be especially useful in libraries.

Comment: so, what's the purpose?